# Recorrido en profundidad de un arbol binario

Tags: java

tengo que realizar un metodo que me devuelva por pantalla los elementos de manera que el mas profundo sea el que primero se imprime y la raiz el ultimo, es decir en orden ascendente.

Tengo la clase :

```
public class BinarySearchTreeADTImpl<T extends Comparable<? super T>> extends
        AbstractBinaryTreeADT<T> {

    /**
     * Devuelve el árbol binario de búsqueda izquierdo.
     */
    protected BinarySearchTreeADTImpl<T> getLeftBST() {
        //  El atributo leftSubtree es de tipo AbstractBinaryTreeADT<T> pero
        //  aquí se sabe que es además de búsqueda binario
        //
        return (BinarySearchTreeADTImpl<T>) leftSubtree;
    }

    private void setLeftBST(BinarySearchTreeADTImpl<T> left) {
        this.leftSubtree = left;
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve el árbol binario de búsqueda derecho.
     */
    protected BinarySearchTreeADTImpl<T> getRightBST() {
        return (BinarySearchTreeADTImpl<T>) rightSubtree;
    }

    private void setRightBST(BinarySearchTreeADTImpl<T> right) {
        this.rightSubtree = right;
    }
```

Cada nodo, tiene un Content, un hijo izquierdo y un hijo derecho. El node en este caso es de tipo Int.

Comment: Cual es tu pregunta?

Comment: ¿Quieres imprimir primero los descendientes IZQ. y DER. y luego el propio nodo? (fácil) ¿O bien quieres que se impriman todos los de la misma profundidad juntos, e ir subiendo de nivel? (más complicado).

Comment: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recorrido_de_%C3%A1rboles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres imprimir primero los descendientes IZQ. y DER. y luego el propio nodo, te pongo un ejemplo aproximado con recursividad:

```
(...)
List<int> resultado = new ArrayList<int>();
NodoArbolBinario nodoPadre;  //lo debes haber rellenado en algún momento...
recorrerArbolBinario(resultado, nodo);
imprimirLista(resultado);
(...)



void recorrerArbolBinario(List<int> resultado, NodoArbolBinario nodo){
    //si tengo descendientes, que hagan primero su parte.
    if (tengo hijo izquierdo?){
        recorrerArbolBinario(resultado, nodo.hijoIzquiero();
    }
    if (tengo hijo derecho?){
        recorrerArbolBinario(resultado, nodo.hijoDerecho();
    }
    //Si soy nodo hoja o mis descendientes ya han hecho su parte, hago la mía.
    resultado.insert(miValor);
}
```